# how align the datepicker right to left?

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

```js
 //datepicker
 $('dob').on('click',function(){
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      "format": "dd/mm/yyyy",
       "autoclose": true
  });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="assets/css/common-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<form class="form-horizontal" action="employee.cfm" method="post" role="form">
 <div class="container col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-8 jumbotron">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="dob">تاریخ پیدائش</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-3">
     <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="DOB" class="form-control datepicker" value="">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

I have created a page in arabic language the content of the page were right to left.In a text field, I have added a datePicker which is not aligned correctly.

I have used commenrtl.css for this.[image]

Comment: show us the page, or some code / screenshot

Comment: @Saqueib I have added a screenshot for you.

Comment: You should use dev tool or firebug to inspect it.

Comment: @Saqueib probably I have founded the issue. 
.dropdown-menu {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: right
}
 when I change the frameWork css file right:0 to left it working.
But it is not the correct way to do.

Comment: If you're using right: and left: values, is this absolutely positioned?

Comment: You'll need to post a code example in your question if you want a meaningful answer.

Comment: @j08691 & Lee please Refer through above code.

Comment: did you find solution for this? I have the same problem and until now I cannot find solution, if you have, please post it

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap datepicker has an orientation option. You can use this to place it left:

```
//datepicker
$('dob').on('click',function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        "format": "dd/mm/yyyy",
         "autoclose": true,
         "orientation": left
    });
});
```

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#orientation

If that doesn't help you could always use a css transform to flip an element:
`transform: rotateY(130deg);` Though it doesn't work in IE9 and lower.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform